# load 2T data from Hive to local server

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have 2TB of data in My hadoop cluster through Hive database and I would bring these data in my local server, So I use Hive to perform this task by using beeline CLI as below:

```
use db1;

for i in (T1 T2 T3 ...)do

export table $1 to '/tmp/$i';

done
```

(Notice: maybe you notice same errors in this query above, it's not what I'm looking for, this syntaxe isn't the same I've used, but it's close enough and it works for me, so don't care about this query).

this query is really slow to done this task, So what I'm looking for actually is to know if there is some other solution like using Scoop or (hadoop fs -get /user/hive/warehouse/database.db) or even hive to do this task as fast as possible.

Comment: What is storage format of these tables? (`show create table T1` and look for `STORED AS`)

Comment: Answered your question on Hortonworks forums